# Use excel and vba pivot tables to summarize data before and after dates

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table, formulas

I have an excel document that is an dumped output of all service tickets(with statuses, assigned to, submitted by...etc) from our ticket tracking software. There is one row per ticket.

I am trying to make a flexible report generator in vba that will allow me to take in the ticket dump and output a report which will have a copy of the data in one sheet, a summary in another sheet, and a line graph in another sheet.

I feel like a pivot table is the perfect approach for this, the only problem is in the summary.

The data from the ticket dump looks something like this:

```
| Submitted_On | Priority |       Title       |    Status    |   Closed_On    |
   10/10/2016        1           Ticket 1           New      
   10/11/2016        1           Ticket 2          Fixed         11/10/2016
   10/12/2016        3           Ticket 3         Rejected        11/9/2016
   10/15/2016        1           Ticket 4        In Review
```

The problem is the way I want the summary to look. Basically the summary should show all tickets that were opened and closed at the first of every month at exactly midnight within the past three years. In other words, if this report was a time machine, at that exact time X would be open and Y would be closed. Furthermore, The summary table should break that down by priority.

The hard part is that these simulated report dates (first of every month within the last 3 years) are extraneous values and are not within each data row.

So the report would be like this:

```
                  |        Open        |       Closed       |
| Reporting Date  |  P1  |  P2  |  P3  |  P1  |  P2  |  P3  |
    1-Oct-2016       6     10      0      3      2      0   
    1-Nov-2016       4     10      0      5      2      0   
    1-Dec-2016       6      3      0      5      9      0
```

Basically the formula for the Open section would be something like:
  `priority=1 AND Submitted_On<Reporting Date  AND (Closed_On>Reporting Date OR Closed_On="")`

and the formula for the closed section would be something like:
  `priority=1 AND Submitted_On<Reporting Date  AND Closed_On<Reporting Date`

It would be needed where I can filter the data so that its only coming assigned to x or only with these statuses...etc. which is why I don't think a regular sheet with formulas would work.

I thought pivot tables would work but `Reporting Date` isn't a field.

Do you have any advice as to what I can do to make this report work and be very flexible as far as filtering goes?

Thank you!

P.S. I am using excel 2010, so I do not have access to queries

Comment: Where's the `Reporting Date` coming from? *Make it* a field, and a pivot should work.

Comment: If you have Excel 2010, you have VBA. If you have VBA, you have adodb. If you have adodb, you can query the sheet itself. Also "flexible" is not really exact behavior. You need specific field calculations and you want design tips for pivots?

Comment: @Mat'sMug The Reporting Date is just a list of the last three years broken down by month.

I can create a reporting date based off of the Submitted date, but that doesn't work because a ticket can be opened in one month and closed in a completely different month. Or a ticket can be opened in 2010 and still open. If I create the reporting date it will only apply to that one row. Idk if that makes sense.

Comment: @RikSportel Im going to look into adodb. By flexible I mean I would like the user to be able to filter the "Data" sheet and have the "Summary" sheet reflect what the users filtered.

Comment: @Kevin I wouldn't go into filtering data sheets. 
Instead look into Pivot tables and Pivot charts. They come with their own filters, "slicers" and charting mechanisms and indeed - these are intended for this purpose.
The **data is just data** and shouldn't be worked on by your end users. If anything that sheet should be hidden. You could add some formulas on it to calculate specific additional fields, but that's about it.
You should use pivot tables and charts to summarize it - E.g. create a dashboard based on the data. From what you describe you don't even need VBA.

Comment: @RikSportel Thanks for your reply, I was thinking pivot tables would be the way to go, but how do I say give me the count of priorities which submitted_on is before this arbitrary date, where multiple arbitrary dates need to be listed in the pivot table? The only thing I can think of is to add a column for each reporting date to the data sheet with a Boolean saying whether or not it is included in that Reporting Date (36 additional columns)

Comment: Hmm yes, you could indeed use VBA for that, but again: If the user sets the date from and date to, they can just use a slicer you provide in the report. 
That's the thing. 
You could also create VBA to come up with a pre filtered data sheet and use that one as a pivot cache - In that case the dates before and after your arbitrary dates will not be available for your end user.
However - these are design questions and not something specific I can script on forehand. It all depends on how you want the behavior to be, exactly.

Comment: @RikSportel I think slicing would work well for the part where the user can  filter, such as showing the pivot table results for particular person it was assigned to, but the pivot table's reporting date is whats difficult. 

How can I list the **arbitrary report dates** as row labels in the pivot table, if an individual data row can be included in multiple report dates.

In other words, the arbitrary report dates are completely independent from the data, and I think anything in the pivot table needs to be in the data right?

Comment: Hi @Kevin - I'm still not completely clear on what you mean with these dates. 
What you would normally do is load the data you want to summarize in some way (e.g. have sheet "data" or "source"). 
From what I understand this data needs to be filtered based on the dates you want. After that you create a pivot on your "summary" sheet, which is based on this "data" sheet and that the users can slice n dice as much as they want. 
Am I correct when I say that you basically only want VBA to alter your "data" sheet (or `pivotcache`) based on these arbitrary dates?